# How to handle background-color tag with Custom Tag Handler in Android?

Tags: android, html, spannablestring

I am using `Html.fromHtml()` to load an HTML formatted string in a `TextView`. But it seems that this method doesn't handle

```
<span style="background-color=#f00">This is highlighted text.</span>
```

How do I load such tags in a `TextView` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load that kind of html tags into TextView. These are the tags supported (not sure if complete) by TextView.

```html
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

To achieve the style specified by your tag, use TextView.setBackgroundColor(int color).